# what is the difference between vh-% and vh-px

Tags: html, css

I am just learned about `vh` and `vw` measurement in the css. I am now doing a small project. In there is a fixed header on top is having `height:15%;`

In the container, i used below code for placing the container below header.

```
min-height: calc( 100vh - 15% );
```

is that possible to do with css?

in my case,it doesn't worked. But i replaced the 15% with 100px its works.

if it is possible, i am curious about to know why?

Comment: The above code does work: https://jsfiddle.net/1fL9a04n/ my question is why mix vh units with % when `15vh` in relation to `15%` are equivelant as `15vh` is `15%` of `100vh`

Comment: in the child i am not used the  `margin-top: 15%;`  . then in parent i am used  `height: 15%;`  can i do in this way? is that wrong?